# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a small problem I try to display information that is in my prices table that is my relationship with table event.

So in my table event: `has_many: prices`
So in my table price: `belongs_to: event`

I get an error: `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

I do not understand why because I actually like this to display the price
`@event.prices [: full_price]`

Here the entrance to my table price:

```
 [#<Price id: 4, full_price: 30, params: ["10", "etudiant et chomeurs"], event_id: 12, created_at: "2015-06-28 20:23:15", updated_at: "2015-06-28 20:23:15">]>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the `full_price` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created `has_many` association which means that for `@event` you'll have many prices.

So `@event.prices` is a collection of prices, but you are trying to access it as a Hash. I don't know what logic you need, but you can:

- Take the first or the last price: `@event.prices.last.full_price`
- Map prices into array and make a comma-separated string out of it: `@event.prices.map(&:full_price).join(", ")`
- Change your association to `has_one` to make `@event.price` be an object, not a collection
- ... many others

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code

```
@event.prices.pluck(: full_price)
```

It displays `array price` list

Hope it helps!